# Inheriting Stylesheets when using CreateDocument

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, document-creation, inheritance

I build a lot of presentations and custom notebooks with very different stylesheets, and use `Button` and `CreateDocument` quite often to accommodate optional/procedurally generated content. For instance,

```
Map[Button[Style[ToString[#] <> " random images", "Text"], 
       CreateDocument[
          {Cell["Here are " <> ToString[#] <> " random image(s)", "Title"],             
           ExpressionCell[Column@Table[RandomImage[2, {200, 200}], {#}],
           "Output"]}]] &,
   Range[5]]
```

What I'd like to do is specify that the notebook generated by `CreateDocument` inherits the StyleSheet from the parent notebook, without having to save the StyleSheet and provide the `StyleSheetPath` Option in the `CreateDocument` function each time I change a style.

I imagine there's an undocumented feature, but haven't found it in my brief searches of StackExchange.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following option to your `CreateDocument` call:

```
StyleDefinitions -> 
 CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]
```

This works for both embedded stylesheets and stylesheets on the StyleSheetPath.  In this case, I use `EvaluationNotebook` to refer to the notebook containing the button but it could, of course, be whatever `NotebookObject` you wish to refer to.

Comment: Well, I should've thought of that. Thanks, John!