# Undocumented "Output" alignment argument to "Column?"

Tags: functions, syntax, grid-layouts

In this SE question, [Inheriting Stylesheets when using CreateDocument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/inheriting-stylesheets-when-using-createdocument), I noticed the literal string argument `"Output"` to `Column`.  I didn't see any documentation for this argument (see below), and I didn't see any effect of the argument:

[image]

and was curious what it does or doesn't do, or what it's supposed to do.

**Silent documentation:**

[image]

Comment: I think Column may be a very forgiving function with Options it does not understand. Try `Column[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}, "Harry"]` or `Column[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}, "Reb.Cabin"]'.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that it will align the column to the first character of the string you put there. So it's an undocumented extension to:

> "c" - align on the character "c"

```
Column[{
  "OffOutputasodas",
  "OutputOffo",
  "adssoadasOffOutput"
  },
 "Output"
 ]
```

> [image]

```
Column[{
  "OffOutputasodas",
  "oOutputOffo",
  "adssoadasOffOutput"
  },
 "output"
 ]
```

> [image]