# Retaining custom style when creating a palette

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, palettes, inheritance

I created a style in a private stylesheet called `"GreenStyle"`.  Here it is

```
Cell[StyleData["GreenStyle"],
 FontColor -> RGBColor[0, 0.67, 0]]
```

In the notebook, I then created a button using this style.

```
Button[Style["My Button", "GreenStyle"],
 , ImageSize -> 120]
```

[image]

When I create a palette using this button, the color will not display as green for some reason.

```
CreatePalette[Button[Style["My Button", "GreenStyle"],
   , ImageSize -> 120]];
```

[image]

Can you explain why I'm getting this behavior?  And what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Palette is a notebook so if you want to use that style there you have to set a stylesheet for it which will contain that style.

The solution is closely related to [**Inheriting Stylesheets when using CreateDocument**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17438/5478) but not as straightforward since your private stylesheet inherits from Default.nb while a palette should from Palette.nb.

Let's replace it then:

```
CreatePalette[
   Button[Style["My Button", "GreenStyle"], ImageSize -> 120],
   StyleDefinitions -> CurrentValue[
     EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions
   ] /. Cell[
      StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]] :> Cell[ 
      StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Palette.nb"]
   ]
];
```

Comment: This works great!  TY.  I've run across Core.nb and Default.nb in editing stylesheets for a notebook, however, I've never run across Palette.nb. Is this the "default" stylesheet for paletes?  Where do I find it?  I'm thinking it may be fun to edit it in a private stylesheet.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Yes it is. It can be found next to all other stylesheets. Here is some more info: [82712](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82712/5478)