# Create notebook with a section extracted from Documentation

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet, documentation, document-creation

I would like to copy a part of a help section into a notebook. The objective is to add comment and save them.

My issue is that, when I copy a part of a help section into a notebook, all the links are broken and some tables are modified.

**How can copy a help section into a notebook while preserving the Documentaion stylesheet?**

Comment: You can use the same `StyleDefinitions`, manually: ``SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb", 
   CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]]`` or like that [**17441**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/inheriting-stylesheets-when-using-createdocument/17441#174410)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that takes a low-level expression (boxes) and resolves all named styles into explicit style specifications for opened Notebook `nb`:

```
resolveAllStyles[expr_, nb_NotebookObject] := With[{
    heads = Cell | StyleBox,
    options = 
     Alternatives @@ Symbol /@ Names["System`" ~~ Except[{"$", "`"}] .. ~~ "Style"],
    resolve = 
     Flatten[Replace[#, 
        style_String :> CurrentValue[nb, {StyleDefinitions, style}], {1}]] &
    },
   Replace[expr, {
     (head : heads)[body_, opts__] :> RuleCondition@head[body, resolve[{opts}]],
     (r : Rule | RuleDelayed)[opt : options, val_] :> RuleCondition@r[opt, resolve[val]]
     }, -2]];
```

And here is how one can extract a Section from a Documentation notebook, convert all the style names into explicit style specifications, and then put this section into an ordinary notebook with default styles:

```
nb = NotebookOpen@
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", "System", 
     "ReferencePages", "Symbols", "Style.nb"}];

(* Select the "Scope" section cell *)
cell = Select[
   Cells[nb, CellStyle -> {"ExampleSection"}], ! 
     FreeQ[NotebookRead[#], s_String /; StringContainsQ[s, "Scope"], -1] &];

(* Select the whole section and extract it *)
sel = SelectionMove[cell[[1]], All, CellGroup];
section = NotebookRead[nb];

(*Create new notebook containing the section extracted from the Documentation Notebook*)
CreateDocument[resolveAllStyles[section, nb], CellGrouping -> Manual];
```

[image: screenshot]