# How can I use the help document style？

Tags: style

[image]

I have spent a lot of time looking for this information on the Internet。Unfortunately,I can not find it。Please help me。Thank you，Thank you。
（I do not how to describe this question。May god forgive me for my poor English。）

Comment: Is the opener that you want [Triangle that collapse cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57463/5478)? or are you looking for how to create full documentation/documentation pages?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Be sure you have learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context. When relevant include minimal working example of code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: closely related q/a: [Create notebook with a section extracted from Documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140320/125)

Comment: @我心永恒 你可以用中文，我懂中文。

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγj就是我想把我的mathematica笔记本的风格弄成帮助文档的风格，我该怎么办。

Comment: @ Kuba yes。 Triangle

Comment: @ rhermans I want the Triangle

Comment: @ kglr I only want the tirangle style。

Comment: then this question is a duplicate of [Triangle that collapse cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57463/5478), no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the ability to click ">" to open and close cells, for the current Notebook, you can set this in the preferences. You can open the Preferences, Click the Advanced Tab and Click the "Open Option Inspector" Button.
[image: Select Open Option Inspector]

Select from the dropdown menu Selected Notebook, and change the Option for Cell Options, Display Options, Show Group Opener to for example "Outside Frame":

[image]

This should give you in this example the ability to open and close cells with clicking ">":
[image]

Comment: Oh，Thank you。I want this。